# Why my Canvas is not on same positions as on my device?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, game-development

I hope I am not too boring because again I have one dumb question.

I have made my game near till end but now I have one big problem. My images , text etc in my Canvas panel are not display correctly on all devices.

I made the game and it looks perfect on unity. Then I build the same game to my Galaxy S8 Device and i realized that some images are out of the screen in other words I can not see some images in corners or some text .. That means my canvas settings are not correct ..

This is my canvas settings.
[image]

When I change UI scale mode to constant pixel or constant physical size It doesn't show properly even in unity or on phone seems like he zoom in automaticlly too much. I made the best settings for UI SCALE MODE - > Scale with screen size, but on some devices it doesn't show up correctly ( it shows with little errors like corner text is not shown because it looks like he is outside of screen)

I hope someone has solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my general settings of canvas, which i always use and never got any issue in positioning.

[image: "Match" value is different from yours.]

Also when you put any object, RectTransform's value(marked in following image) is not set properly then it will go outside of screen.

[image: Set this value according to your requirement]

For more details see : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html

Also you can check different screen ratio from unity and even add new to it and test.

[image: Select any or add new]